# Настройка защищенного подключения через протокол mqtt (mosquitto, ssl)

Tags: websocket, ssl, openssl, mqtt, iot

Как настроить защищенное соединение между клиентом и брокером по протоколу `mqtt` и через веб-сокеты? Брокер [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) на своем сервере. Клиенты разные, от [paho-js](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/js/index.php) до контроллеров от `Wago`.

**PS**: у меня есть ответ на этот вопрос, есть ответы и на англоязычных сайтах, но на *ruSO* я не нашел информации. Я напишу полный ответ в дальнейшем, чтобы поделиться с сообществом. Делитесь опытом и вы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из [документации](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)

> Websockets support is currently disabled by default at compile time.
> Certificate based TLS may be used with websockets, except that only
> the cafile, certfile, keyfile, ciphers, and ciphers_tls1.3 options are
> supported.

Поддержка веб-сокетов в настоящее время отключена по умолчанию во время компиляции. Сертификат на основе TLS может использоваться с веб-сокетами, за исключением того, что поддерживаются только параметры cafile, certfile, keyfile, ciphers и ciphers_tls1.3.

mosquitto.conf - файл конфигурации для mosquitto

вот часть конфиг-файла, который я использую

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true

listener 8883
certfile /certificates/cert.pem
cafile /certificates/cert-ca.pem
keyfile /certificates/key.pem
allow_anonymous false
allow_zero_length_clientid false
password_file /mosquitto/config/passwords
acl_file /mosquitto/config/acl.conf

listener 9001
protocol websockets
certfile /certificates/cert.pem
cafile /certificates/cert-ca.pem
keyfile /certificates/key.pem
allow_anonymous false
allow_zero_length_clientid false
password_file /mosquitto/config/passwords
acl_file /mosquitto/config/acl.conf
```

через порт 1883 можно подключаться и увидеть все топики и сообщения всех брокеров
8883 - для брокеров 
9001 - для WS

Answer (score 1):

Каждая секция `listener`, `bind_address`, `bind_interface` и/или `port` в конфиге `/etc/mosquittо/mosquitto.conf` указывает на начало новой секции конфига, где можно указать параметр `protocol` со значением `websockets`, если при этом указать параметры `cafile, certfile, keyfile, ciphers, ciphers_tls1.3` то сокет получает свой SSL обработчик в зависимости от настроек.

Важно заметить что в Mosquitto протокол вэбсокет отключен вовремя компиляции, то-есть его нужно включить отдельно и пересобрать бинарник.

Больше полезной информации можно найти на https://mosquitto.org/man/ , а именно в разделах

- https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html
- https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html

Ps: Ещё есть вот такой проект: https://github.com/fhmq/hmq Там вообще на коленке можно самому брокер собрать на языке GO и заточить его под свои личные нужды.